# Why my sorting fails for double digits using perl?

Tags: perl

I used this code to filter file names, but it fails to sort properly if the name contains two digits.
How can I make the code make sense?

#### My input from `$output_dir`

```
sample1
sample3
sample14
sample9
```

#### My code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Path qw(remove_tree);

my $path_output = $output_dir;

find1($path_output);

sub find1 {
    my ($s) = @_;

    my (@dirs) = grep { -d } glob $s . '/*';

    my ($link) = sort { 
        my ($m) = $a =~ m/\/(sample\d+)$/;
        my ($n) = $b =~ /\/(rev\d+)$/;
        $n cmp $m
    }
    grep {
        /\/sample\d+$/
    } @dirs;

    foreach ( @dirs ) {
        ( $_ =~ m/sample(\d+)$/ && $_ ne $link ) ? remove_tree($_) : find1($_);
    }
}
```

#### I got the output below from my code

```
sample9
```

#### But my expected output is as follows

```
sample13
```

Why does the sorting and comparison in my code fail to use the two-digit numbers? Instead it is considering only 0-9.

I want to change my code to compare any number of digits. How can I do that?

Comment: then how should i rewrite the same subroutine to bring my expected output.I had tried the above code by schwartzian transform @jm666

Comment: Please don't edit suggested solutions into your question. You must not significantly change the question after you have posted it, or it makes nonsense of all comments and solution written before your change.

Comment: Your code does not use a Schwartzian transform, and in any case you shouldn't be using advanced optimisation techniques like that until you can write ordinary working Perl. You also need to have found that your program runs too slowly, and you should have profiled it to find the critical path. Until then you must write the simplest and most obvious code possible.

Comment: I've asked you not to change your code in a way that makes existing posts irrelevant. You can add additional information if you wish, but please  don't try to fix bugs in your question.

Comment: i had mispelled the word instead of sample i gave rev only that thing i had changed other than that nothing i had edited@Borodin